# Python: determining whether any item in sequence is equal to any other

Tags: python, comparison

I'd like to compare multiple objects and return `True` only if all objects are not equal among themselves. I tried using the code below, but it doesn't work. If obj1 and obj3 are equal and obj2 and obj3 are not equal, the result is `True`.

```
obj1 != obj2 != obj3
```

I have more than 3 objects to compare. Using the code below is out of question:

```
all([obj1 != obj2, obj1 != obj3, obj2 != obj3])
```

Comment: Is the number of objects fixed, or variable?  Are they elements of an array, or in individual variables?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

@Michael Hoffman's answer is good if the objects are all hashable.  If not, you can use [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
>>> all(a != b for a, b in itertools.combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 2))
False
>>> all(a != b for a, b in itertools.combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
True
```

Answer (score 19):

If the objects are all hashable, then you can see whether a `frozenset` of the sequence of objects has the same length as the sequence itself:

```
def all_different(objs):
    return len(frozenset(objs)) == len(objs)
```

Example:

```
>>> all_different([3, 4, 5])
True
>>> all_different([3, 4, 5, 3])
False
```

Comment: This doesn't work if one (or all) of the objects is a unhashable (e.g. a list)

Comment: Why frozenset instead of set?

Comment: I prefer `frozenset` when creating sets that will not be mutated.

Comment: Wouldn't your function be better named `all_different`?

Answer (score 6):

If the objects are unhashable but orderable (for example, lists) then you can transform the `itertools` solution from O(n^2) to O(n log n) by sorting:

```
def all_different(*objs):
    s = sorted(objs)
    return all(x != y for x, y in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]))
```

Here's a full implementation:

```
def all_different(*objs):
    try:
        return len(frozenset(objs)) == len(objs)
    except TypeError:
        try:
            s = sorted(objs)
            return all(x != y for x, y in zip(s[:-1], s[1:]))
        except TypeError:
            return all(x != y for x, y in itertools.combinations(objs, 2))
```

Comment: The check for hashability is far too complex (and also slightly wrong).  The idiomatic way to do this in Python is to try to build a `frozenset()` and catch `TypeError` if this fails.  (The test is slightly wrong because `isinstance(obj, collections.Hashable)` being `True` does not guarantee the object is actually hashable.  It only checks if the object has a type that allows it in principle to be hashed.  Try `([],)` as a counter example.)

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import combinations
all(x != y for x, y in combinations(objs, 2))
```

Comment: That's O(n^2) comparisons - a LOT for large lists.

Answer (score 3):

You can check that all of the items in a list are unique by converting it to a set.

```
my_obs = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
all_not_equal = len(set(my_obs)) == len(my_obs)
```